# My socket.emit doesn't get triggered inside of onchange event

Tags: node.js, express, file, socket.io, onchange

Good day developers, I am working on a chat app, and anytime I  select a file via the input and click, the file get displayed on the screen but the file is not emitted to the server. meanwhile the socket.emit is inside of the onchange event but it doesn't get triggered or sends the data to my server. Please how do I fix this.

Comment: It is unlikely anyone can help you without seeing the relevant code that you're talking about.  Questions about code here must include the relevant code pasted into the question as text and formatted properly as code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.